# Firebase google signin authentication AppDelegate- Use of unresolved identifier 'isMFAEnabled'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-signin, appdelegate

I'm new to iOS development. I am trying to add google sign in to my app but i am facing an some problems.Code shows some "Use of unresolved identifier 'isMFAEnabled"and "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'showTextInputPrompt'".Please help me.I'm following this doc- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#swift_9 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvru7.png)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate {
   
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
           if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
             return
           }

           guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
           let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                             accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
          Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
              let authError = error as NSError
              if (isMFAEnabled && authError.code == AuthErrorCode.secondFactorRequired.rawValue) {
                // The user is a multi-factor user. Second factor challenge is required.
                let resolver = authError.userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoMultiFactorResolverKey] as! MultiFactorResolver
                var displayNameString = ""
                for tmpFactorInfo in (resolver.hints) {
                  displayNameString += tmpFactorInfo.displayName ?? ""
                  displayNameString += " "
                }
                self.showTextInputPrompt(withMessage: "Select factor to sign in\n\(displayNameString)", completionBlock: { userPressedOK, displayName in
                  var selectedHint: PhoneMultiFactorInfo?
                  for tmpFactorInfo in resolver.hints {
                    if (displayName == tmpFactorInfo.displayName) {
                      selectedHint = tmpFactorInfo as? PhoneMultiFactorInfo
                    }
                  }
                  PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(with: selectedHint!, uiDelegate: nil, multiFactorSession: resolver.session) { verificationID, error in
                    if error != nil {
                      print("Multi factor start sign in failed. Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                    } else {
                      self.showTextInputPrompt(withMessage: "Verification code for \(selectedHint?.displayName ?? "")", completionBlock: { userPressedOK, verificationCode in
                        let credential: PhoneAuthCredential? = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID!, verificationCode: verificationCode!)
                        let assertion: MultiFactorAssertion? = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(with: credential!)
                        resolver.resolveSignIn(with: assertion!) { authResult, error in
                          if error != nil {
                            print("Multi factor finanlize sign in failed. Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                          } else {
                            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                          }
                        }
                      })
                    }
                  }
                })
              } else {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
              }
              // ...
              return
            }
            // User is signed in
            // ...
          }
       }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
          let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
          try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
```

Comment: Where did you define `isMFAEnabled`?

Comment: You're using it there, but you didn't declare the variable at all.  That's what the message is trying to tell you.

Comment: Did you solve this, I'm also stuck

Comment: So the real question is rather where can we find the full sample source code...

Comment: I have to say their code is a mess I literally took my hands to my head when organizing their code

Comment: If anyone finding this question anew is wondering where this code is from... it's copied directly from the official Google documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: The docs do not define `isMFAEnabled` before using it, or provide any other clues as to how to define it.

Answer (score 6):

So the boilerplate is wayyyy more code than you need. This is my review of your AppDelegate.

1. **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** looks good as-is.
   Pro tip: add this line for staying logged in `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()`
2. **open,options** looks good as-is.
3. **didSignInFor user** is where it gets tangled. Delete the **entire function** and replace it with the following extension (outside the class' brackets):

(also delete `GIDSignInDelegate` in the class protocols)

```
    extension AppDelegate: GIDSignInDelegate {
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        
        //handle sign-in errors
        if let error = error {
            if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
            } else {
            print("error signing into Google \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        return
        }
        
        // Get credential object using Google ID token and Google access token
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                        accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        // Authenticate with Firebase using the credential object
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("authentication error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I have tested this in today and it's currently working (Swift 5/ios 13.6).

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR; you can just delete that variable if you don't want to enable multi-factor authentication.**

The Firebase documentation provides the variable as a way for you to enable/disable multi-factor (MF) authentication (i.e. when facebook sends you a text message for you to verify). It's more like they are giving you an incomplete template that doesn't compile unless you declare and set this variable (among other things like implementing `showTextInputPrompt`).

The code provided in firebase documentation is an example, so don't expect it to work out of the box.

Comment: Wait... why should you remove `isMFAEnabled`? What is the importance?

Comment: Yeah it's part of the example Firebase provided. It's indicating whether you would want to enable multi-factor auth enabled or not. You can simply ignore it if you want it to be enabled always

Comment: Thanks! Updated your answer with some clarification.